# Efficient way of creating a bit matrix and scan set columns

Tags: java, matrix, bloom-filter

This is my current problem, I have a number of Bloom filters which I wanted to construct into a matrix, say:

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
...
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Each column will be derived from a BitSet, is there a more efficient way to find all columns that have a bits set to 1, apart from looping all rows and comparing each index?

Is there any data structure that could help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for *which* columns contain ones and now *how many* ones each column contains, looping through them seems like the best idea.

If you implement your loops with some **short-circuit** logic, then you'll get a better average running time.

Something like:

```
for (int column = 0; column < width; column++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        if (array[column][row] == 1) {
            list.append(column);
            break;  // move on to the next column because we don't care what's 
                    // left in this column as we already found our '1'
```

With this code, you'll get a **worst-case** (if every `bit` is `0`) running time of `n`  (`n` being the total number of `bits`) which is pretty good.

But unless you're extremely unlucky, you'll get a much better running time due to the **short-circuit** logic.

The above works for arrays of bits, however, `BitSets` have some useful functionality of their own.

A `BitSet` contains the functions: `length()` which returns the highest index with a set bit + 1 (or `0` if there are no set bits) and `nextSetBit(index)` which returns the index of the next set bit from `index -> end` inclusive.

So you're code could easily be something like:

```
int index = 0;

while (index < BitSet.length()) {
    index = BitSet.nextSetBit(index);
    list.append(index);
    index++;
}
```